# Mule:Can CXF create JAXB entity classes given an XML schema in Mule?

Tags: mule, esb

I was going to use XJC to create entity classes for my XML schema. However I was told that CXF is the preferred way of creating these classes in Mule. Could anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Are you using these JAXB annotated objects in the context of JAX-WS web services? If not, you can just use XJC and profit :)

Comment: Oh well, I was able to get the maven CXF plugin & when I ran the project as a Maven project, I was able to generate the JAXB classes based on the XML , thanks for the tip about XJC though.I however had a follow up question: Now that I have gotten my JAXB objects, I can go ahead & in a custom transformer in mule call the setters on the JAXB objects however I have to do a Object to JSON call after this.Given that I have so many JAXB objects how do I reconcile my design to send just 1 object? Does this mandate me changing my schema? Also this takes care of Complex types what about Simple types?